# Why $E(X\mid X^2+Y)=0$ for $(X,Y)$ standard normal?

Tags: expectation

Please help me explain why $E(X\mid X^2+Y)=0$ for $(X,Y)$ standard normal, i.e $(X, Y) \equiv (0, I_2)$.

Comment: What does $X^2+Y$ equal? That's usually required, as the condition needs to be an *event*, not a random variable.

Comment: @trb456 Usually $E[X|Y] = \int E[X|Y=y]f(y)dy$.

Comment: @Lord Soth: Thanks! That makes sense, I guess, but I've not run into that convention. Admittedly, it's been a while for me doing such problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the definition of conditional expectation, it suffices to 
show that  $\mathbb{E}(Xf(X^2+Y))=0$ for every bounded, Borel
measurable function $f$. But this is 
$$\int\int x f(x^2+y)\,\phi(y)\,\phi(x)\, dy\, dx=
\int x \left[\int f(x^2+y)\,\phi(y)\, dy\right] \phi(x)\, dx=
\int x\, \psi(x)\, \phi(x)\, dx,$$
which is zero 
since $\psi(x):=\int f(x^2+y)\,\phi(y)\, dy$ is an even function of $x$.
Here $\phi$ is the density of a standard normal distribution, also an even 
function.

Comment: Why $E(Xf(X^2+Y))=0$ implies $E(X|X^2+Y)=0$?  I did not see it.

Answer (score 1):

The simple explanation for "why" is that knowing $X^2+Y$ tells you nothing about the sign of X ($X \mapsto X^2$ is even) and so after conditioning on $X^2+Y$, $X$ is still symmetrically distributed